# 403 error while sharing a url using linkedIn Share plug in

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

I am trying to share a url on linkedIn using LinkedInn share plugin but getting the following error

```
Error while processing route: inshare.index Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard%2Fexpert%2Fd2193931-a0f1-4860-825b-ad9a7cf9122d returned a 500


The URL seems to work fine on facebook and twitter but not on linked, I tried inspecting the url using Linkedin Post inspector and it is giving '403 Failure'

 Error while processing route: inshare.index Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard%2Fexpert%2Fd2193931-a0f1-4860-825b-ad9a7cf9122d returned a 500

Payload (application/json)
[object Object] Error: Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdashboard%2Fexpert%2Fd2193931-a0f1-4860-825b-ad9a7cf9122d returned a 500
Payload (application/json)
[object Object]
    at n (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/9tfzf1lqp8bajtgaz27f4wo8v:562:13)
    at n.j (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/br5327i9hgtilu8fd4j4tjynx:6460:36)
    at new n (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/br5327i9hgtilu8fd4j4tjynx:6461:54)
    at n.handleResponse (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/br5327i9hgtilu8fd4j4tjynx:7025:26)
    at n.handleResponse (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/br5327i9hgtilu8fd4j4tjynx:5739:224)
    at n (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/9tfzf1lqp8bajtgaz27f4wo8v:2837:9)
    at n.handleResponse (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/br5327i9hgtilu8fd4j4tjynx:3013:49)
    at n [as handleResponse] (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/9tfzf1lqp8bajtgaz27f4wo8v:2837:9)
    at n.handleResponse (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/br5327i9hgtilu8fd4j4tjynx:5442:401)
    at n [as handleResponse] (https://static.licdn.com/sc/h/br/9tfzf1lqp8bajtgaz27f4wo8v:2837:9)
(anonymous) @ 9tfzf1lqp8bajtgaz27f4wo8v:2583
ib.adnxs.com/mapuid?member=232&user=AfKidfL4KJpxQRBVIWx7PhgF6zu4&redir=https%3A%2F%2Fdc.ads.linkedin.com%2Fcollect%2F%3Fpid%3D6883%26li_id%3DAgAAGuMDAc8sAYxT14H13FvkHbO9YvK5ZTBDmIQ8TA%26li_oo%3Dfalse%26li_update%3Dfalse%26li_active%3Dtrue%26max_age%3D86400%26fmt%3Dgif:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a plugin for simple simple things, you can use this

```html
<a class="your classname" href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">Linkedin text or icon</a>
```